# Building a webapp to serve multiple HG repositories

Tags: django, mercurial

I know there are cgi scripts to serve multiple mercurial repositories, but I'm trying to create a django web app which will do this. For instance, think along the lines of bitbucket or any other repository hosting site.

**What's the best way (or anyway, really) to do this?**

Basically, what I need to do is provide an implementation of the Merucrial [HttpCommandProtocol](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HttpCommandProtocol) at project-specific URLs on my site, so that mercurial clients can sync their repos with the one stored on the site. I thought I could use `hglib` to do this, but there doesn't seem to be any straightforward mapping between CommandServer commands and HttpCommandProtocol commands. I could implement the HttpCommandProtocol myself: I've successfully done a few of them, but most of the commands are not documented and I can't figure out what they are supposed to do.

Another option would be to run `hg serve` for each repository and essentially do a pass through from the client to the hg server, but there could be any number of repos, and each server would need to be on a different port, unless there's some way I can talk to the HttpServer's over a pipe or file descriptor, instead of a TCP port. You can do this with `hg serve --commandserver pipe`, but the CommandServer protocol isn't what's needed of HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with the terms of the GPL the easiest way to do this is definitely just to invoke hgweb from your django views.  hgweb is a full-function, multi-repository python wsgi application, of the sort django loves to work with.

It's entirely possible your entire django view could be:

```
from mercurial.hgweb import hgweb

def hg_view(request):
    """ relay a WSGI Request to HG """
    hgweb(config).run_wsgi(request)
```

and you'd route to that with a normal django view.  You'd probably have to modify the request to remove the leading path element, but the larger point is if the goal is to have a wsgi application (which django is) call another wsgi application (which hgweb is) it's definitely easiest to avoid TCP sockets and local pipes and instead keep things all in the family.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! As soon as I can test it out and verify that it works, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: It won't work exactly like that, but it won't be far off.  Remember that this is "linking" to GPL code, so you can use this, and you can offer it as a web service, and you distribute it as GPL, but you can't "distribute" it without it being under the terms of the GPL.

Comment: Thanks, I grok GPL =). I'm not clear on how to properly integrate a separate WSGI app (hgweb) into django: I don't think Django's request object, that it passes to the view function, is actually a WSGI request that can be passed to `run_wsgi`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm only going what what I recall seeing in error output, but I did think the django request was a subclass of WSGIRequest.  If it's not you can probably instantiate a wsgirequest using the pieces of the django request, but I really think what's above will come pretty close to working.

Comment: I added an additional answer just for completeness: it wraps the django request for use by wsgi, and wraps the wsgi stuff for use by django. It may not all be necessary, and it probably won't cover all cases, but it's working well for me. I still accepted your answer as it got me most of the way there, so thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is **the solution I actually went with**, based on Ry4an's accepted answer. It's entirely possible that a django `HttpRequest` object can serve as a `wsgirequest` that can be passed directly to `hgweb_mod.run_wsgi`, but I couldn't figure out what to return then. The following worked for me, it certainly doesn't handle all the edge cases, but I'm able to push and pull my repos this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class WsgiWrapper(object):
    """
    A wrapper object that works reasonably well (at least in the cases in which it is currently being used)
    to turn a django request into a Wsgi thingy.
    """
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
        self.status = None
        self.headers = None
        self.exc_info = None

    def __call__(self, status=None, response_headers=None, exc_info=None):
        if status is not None:
            self.status = status
        self.headers = response_headers
        self.exc_info = exc_info

        self.outputbuffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
        return self.outputbuffer.write


def serve_hg(request, repopath):
    """
    Delegates to mercurial's built-in hgweb WSGI application to serve up access
    to mercurial HTTPCommand Protocol.
    """

    #Put together a wsgi request from the django request.
    wrapper = WsgiWrapper(request)
    env = {}
    env.update(request.META)
    env['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '/'
    env['PATH_INFO'] = '/'
    req = hgweb.request.wsgirequest(env, wrapper)

    #Invoke hgweb as a wsgi application.
    hgw = hgweb.hgweb(repopath)
    hgw.repo.baseui.setconfig('web', 'allow_push', '*')
    hgw.repo.baseui.setconfig('web', 'push_ssl', 'false')
    gen = hgw.run_wsgi(req)
    data = wrapper.outputbuffer.getvalue()
    if len(data):
        gen = [data]
    wrapper.outputbuffer.close()

    #Now build up the django response object from that.
    resp = HttpResponse("".join(gen))
    stat = wrapper.status
    if stat is None:
        resp.status_code = 200
    else:
        pair = stat.split(' ', 1)
        resp.status_code = pair[0]
        if len(pair) > 1:
            resp.reason_phrase = pair[1]

    hopbyhop = (
        'Connection',
        'Keep-Alive',
        'Proxy-Authenticate',
        'Proxy-Authorization',
        'TE',
        'Trailers',
        'Transfer-Encoding',
        'Upgrade',
    )
    if wrapper.headers is not None:
        for k, v in wrapper.headers:
            if k not in hopbyhop:
                resp[k] = v

    return resp
```